# I get import gyp error when try to install package for electron

Tags: python, windows, electron, node-gyp, gyp

I tried to install on Windows the demo from this repository:
https://github.com/Seo-Rii/electron-acrylic-window

```
git clone https://github.com/Seo-Rii/electron-acrylic-window.git
cd electron-acrylic-window
yarn install
```

But installation returned next error:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated stringify-package@1.0.1: This module is not used anymore, and has been replaced by @npmcli/package-json
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\test\electron-acrylic-window\node_modules\@seorii\win32-displayconfig
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm run rebuild
npm ERR! > @seorii/win32-displayconfig@0.1.1 rebuild
npm ERR! > node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.10.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Users\Aptyp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.6.33829.357) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Aptyp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\test\\electron-acrylic-window\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\test\\electron-acrylic-window\\node_modules\\@seorii\\win32-displayconfig\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\test\\electron-acrylic-window\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Aptyp\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.10.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Aptyp\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.10.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=E:\\test\\electron-acrylic-window\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Aptyp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.10.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=E:\\test\\electron-acrylic-window\\node_modules\\@seorii\\win32-displayconfig',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\test\\electron-acrylic-window\\node_modules\\@seorii\\win32-displayconfig\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "E:\test\electron-acrylic-window\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp  # noqa: E402
npm ERR!     ^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "E:\test\electron-acrylic-window\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp.input
npm ERR!   File "E:\test\electron-acrylic-window\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 19, in <module>
npm ERR!     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (E:\test\electron-acrylic-window\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:259:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\test\\electron-acrylic-window\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\test\electron-acrylic-window\node_modules\@seorii\win32-displayconfig
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

I installed last Python and Visual Studio, but there was no positive effect. I looked through a lot of information but still didn’t understand what it was missing. This is my first acquaintance with **electron**.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you *really* want to use this library. Its last update was two years ago, it doesn't seem maintained anymore.

You get this error because of a problem of compatibility. According to the logs, you use:

```
node-gyp v8.4.1
node v20.10.0
Python v3.12.0
```

And the error you get is:

```bash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

This is because [`distutils` has been removed in Python v3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#summary-release-highlights). To fix this, you either need to upgrade you version of `node-gyp` (to v10+), or downgrade your version of Python (and maybe NodeJS too).

---

**Additional notes:**

- Transparency effects are natively available with the `vibrancy` API on MacOS [#7898](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/7898)
- Transparency effects should be also available for Windows since Electron [v24.4.0](https://releases.electronjs.org/release/v24.4.0), but the API is currently unstable [#38163](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/38163)

Comment: I've tried to do it with standart backgroundMaterial: 'acrylic' using the latest version of Electron, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Artur I don't know how it work, I never tried myself, I can only give you the resources for these options, and answer your question.